# Para que servem Testes Unitários e quais as vantagens?

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade

Vi alguns videos e artigos sobre testes de unidades, aprendi o framework QUnit e algumas situações de teste.

Ainda assim não consegui pensar num uso prático que valha mais a pena do que uma depuração comum no browser ou tratamento de excessões, etc.

Quando e como devo realmente usar um framework de testes unitários?

Answer (score 31):

Imagine o seguinte cenário: Você tem aquele programa enorme com uns trocentos módulos.

E então você tem que mexer alguma coisa lá no meio. Talvez seja pegar uma classe ou uma função e dividir em duas, mudar a forma de alguns parâmetros, fazer alguma mudança em uma determinada estrutura, qualquer coisa assim.

Como você sabe que a sua mudança deu certo e não quebrou nada que já estava funcionando? Simples, é "só" testar. E como você testa? É só abrir o seu programa, começar a colocar dados, e ficar de olho se ele se comporta da forma esperada. Também é pertinente fazer testes de situações de erros, quando o sistema é alimentado com dados incorretos ou está executando em um ambiente com problemas, para ver se tudo corre como o esperado. Se você ver que alguma coisa quebrou inesperadamente, você tem o que é chamado de *regressão*.

Mas testar não é algo fácil, principalmente quando o sistema é grande. Além disso, fazer tudo isso manualmente é:

- Muito chato, ficar executando manualmente sempre os mesmos testes para se certificar de que nada quebrou de forma inesperada.
- Sujeito a erros, pois muitas vezes você se esquece de testar alguma situação ou algum caso especial, que foi justamente o que você quebrou.
- Demorado, pois para testar todas as funcionalidades do sistema, demora-se um tempão, principalmente para um sistema grande com centenas de funcionalidades.

Bem, como podemos atacar estes problemas? Todos estes problemas do teste manual são centrados no fato de que quem está testando é uma pessoa. O trabalho é repetitivo, cansativo e demorado. E se fizessemos um programa que executasse o teste automaticamente?

Então é aí que surge o teste automatizado! Você escreve um programa que vai abrir as funcionalidades do sistema, entrar com dados e verificar se os resultados batem com o que era esperado. O seu teste automatizado também vai simular situações de erro para ver se o seu programa reage a ele da forma esperada. Assim:

- Executar o teste automatizado não é mais algo chato. Apenas clique em um botão, deixe ele trabalhar sozinho e no final ele diz se deu tudo certo ou não.
- Não é mais sujeito a erros, pois o seu teste automatizado vai sempre fazer o teste do mesmo jeito. Assim, você não corre o risco de esquecer-se de testar algo.
- O teste não é mais demorado (pelo menos não tanto quanto um humano), pois ele não precisa ficar esperando um ser de carne e osso ficar digitando, arrastando o mouse ou se lembrando de qual é a próxima coisa a fazer no teste.

Ok, mas teste automatizado e teste de unidade são coisas um pouco diferentes. O que é exatamente um teste de unidade?

Um código bem-projetado é modular e por causa disso faz sentido que você possa testar os módulos de forma independente uns dos outros. Além disso, uma modularização bem-feita reduz os riscos de você ter alterações em funcionalidades cascateando efeitos colaterais aonde não é esperado. E é isso que é o teste de unidade: O teste de unidade consiste em um teste automatizado cuja finalidade é executar testes apenas em uma pequena unidade isolada do seu sistema.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você usou esta função javascript:

```js
function valida_data(dia, mes, ano) {
    return dia <= 31 && mes <= 12;
}
```

Talvez você note que há algo de errado nela. Mas vamos supor que isto passou desapercebido e no meio do seu sistema enorme ela está ali. Então de repente alguém diz que na parte de emissão de nota fiscal apareceu uma data de 31 de abril. Você então vai começar a fazer um monte de *debug* nas notas fiscais, no banco de dados, ficar horas e horas a fio tentando achar o bug, até você enfim chegar nesta função. E então você corrige para isso:

```js
function valida_data(dia, mes, ano) {
    var dias = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    return dia <= dias[mes] && mes <= 12;
}
```

E pronto, o dia 31 de abril é corretamente rejeitado.

Alguns meses depois, alguém reclama que houve um erro na integração com o XML do banco de dados. Você vai procurar no XML e tem um monte de mensagens de erro malucas no log, fica rastreando e *debuggando* aquilo a noite inteira e descobre que foi algo que deu errado no dia 31 de agosto. Depois de várias horas de *debug* você volta na função `valida_data` e finalmente percebe que para agosto está 30 e não 31.

Ok, você já perdeu duas noites quebrando a cabeça por causa dessa função. Será que não existe mais nada de errado nela? Bem, vamos criar alguns testes para saber:

```js
function testa_valida_data() {
    if (!valida_data(1, 1, 2015)) throw new Error("Não aceitou 1 de janeiro");
    if (!valida_data(31, 1, 2015)) throw new Error("Não aceitou 31 de janeiro");
    if (valida_data(32, 1, 2015)) throw new Error("Aceitou 32 de janeiro");
    if (valida_data(30, 2, 2016)) throw new Error("Aceitou 30 de fevereiro");
    if (!valida_data(29, 2, 2016)) throw new Error("Não aceitou 29 de fevereiro");
    if (valida_data(29, 8, 2015)) throw new Error("Não aceitou 29 de agosto");
    if (valida_data(31, 3, 2015)) throw new Error("Não aceitou 31 de março");
    if (!valida_data(31, 4, 2015)) throw new Error("Aceitou 31 de abril");
    // ... Outros testes
}
```

Se você executar a função `testa_valida_data()`, ela vai lançar um erro! Isso daí te dá a certeza de que há algo de errado na função `valida_data()`. Então você vai na função e mexe ela. Para saber se o que você fez está certo, basta rodar a `testa_valida_data()` mais uma vez. Quando a função `testa_valida_data()` não lançar um erro, então **talvez** a função `valida_data` esteja certa.

Por que talvez? Porque se o teste de unidade passar, não há como garantir que não haja mais nenhum detalhe esquecido. Por outro lado se ele falhar, então você tem a certeza que há algo de errado e o teste já vai te dizer o que está errado e de onde veio o erro, economizando muito tempo de *debug*. Além disso, embora o teste de unidade não possa te garantir que o seu código está correto, quanto mais e melhores os testes, menor é a probabilidade de que algo que esteja errado possa ter sido esquecido.

E o QUnit? O QUnit é um framework que te dá maleabilidade e gerenciabilidade nos testes. Afinal, se mantermos as coisas como estão no `testa_valida_data()` e houver vários erros, ele só vai mostrar o primeiro e parar. Além disso, se houver várias funções ou módulos para testar, ainda teremos que chamar as funções de teste manualmente. Com o QUnit isso é mitigado. Veja este exemplo:

```js
function valida_data(dia, mes, ano) {
    var dias = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    return dia <= dias[mes] && mes <= 12;
}

QUnit.test("Testa dias normais", function(assert) {
    assert.ok(valida_data( 1,  1, 2015), "Aceitar 1 de janeiro");
    assert.ok(valida_data( 7,  8, 2015), "Aceitar 7 de agosto");
    assert.ok(valida_data(13, 12, 2015), "Aceitar 13 de dezembro");
});

QUnit.test("Testa últimos dias", function(assert) {
    assert.ok(valida_data(31,  1, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de janeiro");
    assert.ok(valida_data(28,  2, 2015), "Aceitar 28 de fevereiro");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31,  3, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de março");
    assert.ok(valida_data(30,  4, 2015), "Aceitar 30 de abril");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31,  5, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de maio");
    assert.ok(valida_data(30,  6, 2015), "Aceitar 30 de junho");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31,  7, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de julho");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31,  8, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de agosto");
    assert.ok(valida_data(30,  9, 2015), "Aceitar 30 de setembro");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31, 10, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de outubro");
    assert.ok(valida_data(30, 11, 2015), "Aceitar 30 de novembro");
    assert.ok(valida_data(31, 12, 2015), "Aceitar 31 de dezembro");
});

QUnit.test("Testa além dos últimos dias", function(assert) {
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32,  1, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de janeiro");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(30,  2, 2015), "Rejeitar 30 de fevereiro");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32,  3, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de março");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(31,  4, 2015), "Rejeitar 31 de abril");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32,  5, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de maio");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(31,  6, 2015), "Rejeitar 31 de junho");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32,  7, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de julho");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32,  8, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de agosto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(31,  9, 2015), "Rejeitar 31 de setembro");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32, 10, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de outubro");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(31, 11, 2015), "Rejeitar 31 de novembro");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32, 12, 2015), "Rejeitar 32 de dezembro");
});

QUnit.test("Testa zeros e negativos", function(assert) {
    assert.notOk(valida_data(-1,  1, 2015), "Rejeitar dia negativo");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 0,  1, 2015), "Rejeitar dia zero");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 1,  0, 2015), "Rejeitar mês zero");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 1, -1, 2015), "Rejeitar mês negativo");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 0,  0, 2015), "Rejeitar mês e dia zero");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 0, -1, 2015), "Rejeitar dia zero de mês negativo");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(-1,  0, 2015), "Rejeitar dia negativo e mês zero");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(-1, -1, 2015), "Rejeitar dia e mês negativo");
});

QUnit.test("Testa bissextos", function(assert) {
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 2015), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.ok   (valida_data(29,  2, 2016), "Aceitar 29 de fevereiro bissexto");
    assert.ok   (valida_data(29,  2, 2000), "Aceitar 29 de fevereiro bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1999), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1998), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1997), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.ok   (valida_data(29,  2, 1996), "Aceitar 29 de fevereiro bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1900), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1800), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 1700), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
    assert.ok   (valida_data(29,  2, 1600), "Aceitar 29 de fevereiro bissexto");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(29,  2, 2100), "Rejeitar 29 de fevereiro não-bissexto");
});

QUnit.test("Testa mês depois de dezembro", function(assert) {
    assert.notOk(valida_data(10, 13, 2015), "Rejeitar dia do mês 13.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(10, 14, 2015), "Rejeitar dia do mês 14.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 0, 13, 2015), "Rejeitar dia zero do mês 13.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data( 0, 14, 2015), "Rejeitar dia zero do mês 14.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(-1, 13, 2015), "Rejeitar dia negativo do mês 13.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(-1, 14, 2015), "Rejeitar dia negativo do mês 14.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32, 13, 2015), "Rejeitar dia 32 do mês 13.");
    assert.notOk(valida_data(32, 14, 2015), "Rejeitar dia 32 do mês 14.");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.6.0.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.6.0.js"></script>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

Se você executar os testes acima, verá que muitos deles falham. A função `valida_data()` que providenciei é propositadamente falha, e basta clicar no botão "<kbd>► Executar</kbd>" aí em cima para ver isso.

Se você copiar e colar este *snippet* em algum outro lugar e alterar a função `valida_data()`, você pode verificar se as suas alterações estão corretas apenas ao clicar em um botão. Com isso, você pode ficar alterando ela e rapidamente saber se o que você fez está ou não certo, até todos os testes passarem. Deixo esta tarefa como um (fácil) exercício para o leitor. :)

Vamos então supor que você alterou o código da função até todos os testes passarem. Se algum tempo depois disso (possivelmente anos depois), você por algum motivo tiver que alterar a função (ex: achou uma forma com um desempenho melhor), então, como saber se você não bagunçou com nada ou introduziu algum bug? É só clicar no botão "<kbd>► Executar</kbd>" e ver o resultado. Se você introduziu algum erro, é bem provável que ele apareça lá. Se o teste não acusou nenhum erro, provavelmente as suas alterações são válidas e confiáveis. **E assim você consegue ter um teste rápido, completo, eficiente e detalhado com apenas um clique.**

Além disso, se anos depois alguém encontrar um bug que não estava coberto em nenhum teste, tudo o que você precisa fazer é acrescentar um teste para o bug, e alterar o código para consertá-lo. O seu teste acaba servindo como um guarda contra regressões. Pois se o bug voltar, o teste quebrará e denunciará este fato. E obviamente, se um novo bug for introduzido, os testes existentes têm uma alta probabilidade de denunciá-lo.

Por outro lado, para ser franco, há um aspecto negativo: Você precisa escrever o código de teste, ele não cai do céu! E escrever código de teste toma algum tempo, mas você economizará este tempo posteriormente com *debugging* que você **não** vai precisar fazer. Além disso, ter uma ampla e boa cobertura de testes é difícil, mas mesmo assim quanto maior a cobertura dos testes, menor a probabilidade de que alguma alteração no código quebre alguma coisa de forma inesperada.

E é claro, é possível (e bem comum) que os testes estejam errados, o que resulta em testes que aceitam código errado, ou rejeitam código certo, ou que simplesmente não testam adequadamente o que eles se propõem a testar. Também é comum que existam testes frágeis, que quebram por causa de alterações inócuas e inofensivas, ou então testes frouxos, que não quebram mesmo quando ocorrerem alterações nocivas e perigosas. Estes problemas com testes podem ter várias causas, tais como: má qualidade do código testado; má qualidade do código de teste; baixa cobertura do teste sobre o código testado; e requisitos do projeto confusos e mal-definidos (como você vai testar adequadamente algo que nem você sabe exatamente o que deve fazer?). Enfim, escrever bons testes também demanda uma certa experiência, mas para se ter experiência, só há um jeito: colocar a mão na massa e praticar.

Link de onde obter o QUnit: https://qunitjs.com/

Answer (score 15):

Testes de Unidade, ou Testes Unitários, têm como objetivo se certificar que certas unidades de processamento (em geral métodos e funções) não apenas façam o que se espera delas, mas que **continuem** fazendo isso mesmo quando o sistema **evolui**. Em outras palavras, se uma determinada função hoje recebe a entrada X e produz a saída Y, criar um teste de unidade onde se assegura (*assert*) que isso realmente ocorre ajuda a garantir que, mesmo quando essa função ou uma de suas dependências seja alterada no futuro, esse comportamento se mantenha.

Sendo assim, os testes de unidade de um sistema constituem uma forma de **contrato informal** - além dos contratos formais impostos por uma determinada linguagem (ex.: o método F recebe três parâmetros, com os tipos A, B e C, e retorna um valor com o tipo D; a classe X implementa as interfaces Y e Z; etc), muitas vezes é desejável - porém difícil de se obter na prática - que exista também um contrato em relação à **semântica** do código. Poderia-se usar vários [métodos formais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todos_formais) para se garantir essa semântica - como por exemplo, provas lógicas da correção de determinado código, que demonstre que ele é uma implementação correta de um determinado algoritmo expresso em lógica matemática. Entretanto, o *custo* para se atingir tal nível de rigor nem sempre compensa...

Por outro lado, é relativamente fácil se produzir **exemplos** de entradas e saídas que satisfaçam uma determinada lógica. Esses exemplos podem não ser suficientes para provar acima de qualquer dúvida que uma implementação está correta, mas se bem escolhidos podem dar uma boa cobertura dos casos mais "interessantes" (onde se espera uma descontinuidade nos valores de saída em relação às entradas). Um teste de unidade pode não *provar* que uma semântica está correta, mas ele pode **refutar** quando a mesma não está.

Sobre quando e como usar, não sei se sou a melhor pessoa para responder (a única coisa que eu tenho certeza é que *eu* os uso menos do que deveria...), mas posso dar algumas indicações baseado no modo como eu percebo a função dos mesmos:

- Se você fez uma "depuração comum" e encontrou resultados inválidos - para depois corrigi-los - ajuda criar testes com esses resultados de modo a garantir que esses problemas não voltem no futuro (i.e. esses testes unitários em particular *também* seriam testes de regressão);
- Se uma função ou classe é dependência para várias outras, as consequências de uma mudança inesperada de comportamento na mesma seria bem maior do que numa que não é dependência pra ninguém - uma pequena alteração nela pode causar um número bem grande de bugs em outras partes do código. Assim, embora o ideal é que todo o código seja bem testado, deve-se dar uma atenção maior às partes que são reutilizadas com mais frequência;
- Se a implementação de um algoritmo é complexa - com muitos `if`s, *loops* incomuns (i.e. mais complexo que "percorra a lista X"), etc - não só é mais provável que ela contenha bugs, como é bem possível que você mesmo não a entenda 100% (apesar de tê-la escrito). Nesse caso, não só é bom criar testes para garantir a sua correção, como também para testar seus casos limite:

  - Garanta que todas as linhas de código sejam percorridas em pelo menos um teste cada;
  - Se viável, garanta também que cada *combinação* delas seja ativada em ao menos um teste (ex.: há dois `if`s A e B, crie um teste em que ele não entre em nenhum dos dois, um que ele entre nos dois, um que entre em A mas não em B e outro que entre em B mas não em A);
  - Descubra quais são os casos "interessantes" e produza um teste para eles. Por exemplo, se a função recebe um inteiro, crie um teste passando zero, outro um, outro menos um, outro `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, etc. Se ela utiliza o seno de um ângulo num cálculo, faça com que esse ângulo seja, 0, 90º, 180º, 270º, 360º e -90º (ajustando os parâmetros do teste para que isso ocorra). Se ela espera "uma lista com pelo menos dois elementos" crie um teste onde a lista em dois, outro onde ela tem três, outro onde ela tem um e outro onde ela está vazia. Etc.
- Reduza as ["variáveis de confusão"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_de_confus%C3%A3o) (*confounding*): se a unidade que você está querendo testar depende de várias outras (ex.: uma função que chama outras, uma classe que herda de outra) procure - dentro das capacidades de sua linguagem/plataforma, é claro - substituir essas dependências por *mock-ups* que sempre dêem o resultado certo. É bastante indesejável que um teste de unidade para a função X falhe não porque X está incorreto, mas sim porque Y que é chamada por X está.

  É sempre bom criar muitos testes para Y também, é claro (vide o segundo ponto acima), mas como já dito esses testes não provam que uma função está correta, apenas dão exemplos. Se todos os testes para Y passaram, mas X chama Y com um parâmetro distinto de todos eles, que faz com que Y falhe, então temos um problema... Caso isso aconteça (e de vez em quando acontece, apesar dos nossos melhores esforços), crie novos testes para Y baseado no resultado da sua depuração de X (vide o primeiro ponto acima).

Por fim, não custa relembrar que esses testes não valem de nada se você não executá-los. Sempre! Não uma vez aqui, outra ali, mas de preferência toda vez que você fizer qualquer alteração no seu sistema. Alguns *workflows* exigem que esses testes sejam executados em cada compilação (quando a etapa de compilação é separada da de execução) - o que pode ser um problema caso os testes demorem demais para terminar, principalmente se ele estiver testando de novo e de novo partes do programa que não foram alteradas. Quanto a isso, receio ter muito pouco a sugerir nesse momento (não conheço nenhum *framework* de testes unitários que *também* faça uma gestão decente das dependências - só re-executando testes nas unidades que realmente poderiam ter sido afetadas pela última alteração). Talvez alguém com mais experiência no assunto possa nos dar melhores notícias, espero...