# Substituir ocorrências arbitrariamente em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou usando o método `replace()` a fim de destacar certas palavras numa sentença. O método substitui apenas a 1ª ocorrência da palavra-alvo, por padrão.
Gostaria de saber como ***realizar substituições arbitrárias***. Ex: Substituir a 2ª ocrorência da palavra em um caso, noutro substituir a 1ª e 3ª ocorrências, outro a 2ª e 3ª, etc.
Abaixo, a sentença contêm 3 ocorrências da palavra "acima":

```
var stc = 'acima do limite da razão, acima da capacidade do cérebro, acima de tudo.'
var plv = 'acima'; // palavra-alvo
var rpl = new RegExp("\\b" + plv + "\\b");
var plv_subs = '<span class="myclass">acima</span>'; // palavra estilizada.
var ocr = 2; // ocorrência(s).

stc = stc.replace(rpl, plv_subs); // substituição normal.
```

A ideia é ***realizar uma substituição 'normal', caso o valor da variável*** `ocr` ***seja*** `false`, mas caso o valor seja 2, por exemplo, apenas a 2ª ocorrência deve ser substituída. Também gostaria, como mencionei no início, se possível, **fornecer todas as ocorrências de uma só vez**, na mesma variável. Exemplo: `var ocr = 2-3`, (é claro que talvez não possa ser escrito assim!), substituiria a 2ª e 3ª ocorrências, e `var ocr = 1,3`, substituiria a 1ª e 3ª ocorrências. De preferência, a solução deve usar o método `replace()`, mas estou aberto a outras ideias. Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz a função `replaceString` que se segue baseando-se no segundo código que é demonstrado [nesta seção deste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Example:_Replacing_a_substring_within_a_string).

Para provar que funciona inclui [testes de unidade com o QUnit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53681/132), então basta cocê clicar no botão "► Executar trecho de código" que está mais abaixo para testar.

```js
function replaceString(oldS, newS, fullS, ocr) {
  var temOcr = arguments.length >= 4;
  var parts = fullS.split(oldS);
  var substituicoes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    substituicoes[i] = temOcr ? oldS : newS;
  }
  if (temOcr) {
    for (var e in ocr) {
      var idx = ocr[e] - 1;
      if (idx >= 0 && idx < substituicoes.length) substituicoes[idx] = newS;
    }
  }
  var result = parts[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < substituicoes.length; i++) {
    result += substituicoes[i] + parts[i + 1];
  }
  return result;
}

QUnit.test("Testa a função replaceString", function(assert) {
  var testando = 'acima do limite da razão, acima da capacidade do cérebro, acima de tudo.';
  var resultadoEsperado = '<span class="myclass">acima</span> do limite da razão, <span class="myclass">acima</span> da capacidade do cérebro, <span class="myclass">acima</span> de tudo.';
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [1, 2, 3]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui todos os índices");
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando), resultadoEsperado, "Omitindo os índices");

  resultadoEsperado = '<span class="myclass">acima</span> do limite da razão, acima da capacidade do cérebro, <span class="myclass">acima</span> de tudo.';
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [1, 3]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui alguns dos índices (1, 3)");
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [3, 1]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui alguns dos índices, mesmo fora de ordem (1, 3)");
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [3, 3, 1, 1]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui alguns dos índices, mesmo com repetição (1, 3)");

  resultadoEsperado = 'acima do limite da razão, <span class="myclass">acima</span> da capacidade do cérebro, <span class="myclass">acima</span> de tudo.';
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [2, 3]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui alguns dos índices (2, 3)");

  resultadoEsperado = 'acima do limite da razão, <span class="myclass">acima</span> da capacidade do cérebro, acima de tudo.';
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [2]), resultadoEsperado, "Substitui um dos índices (2)");

  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, []), testando, "Não substitui nada");
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [4]), testando, "Tenta substituir além da última ocorrência");
  assert.equal(replaceString('abacaxi', 'banana', testando, []), testando, "Não substitui nada por algo que não existe na frase");
  assert.equal(replaceString('abacaxi', 'banana', testando, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), testando, "Tenta substituir por algo que não existe na frase");
  assert.equal(replaceString('acima', '<span class="myclass">acima</span>', testando, [-4, 7, 2, 0, 2, -2]), resultadoEsperado, "Tenta substituir com índices inválidos (2)");
  
  assert.equal(replaceString('arara', 'papagaio', 'zarararararaz', [1, 2]), 'zpapagaiorpapagaioz', "Verifica se ocorrências não se sobrepõem (1, 2)");
  assert.equal(replaceString('arara', 'papagaio', 'zarararararaz', [2]), 'zarararpapagaioz', "Verifica se ocorrências não se sobrepõem (2)");

  assert.equal(replaceString('ana', 'banana', 'ana e mariana gostam de banana', [1, 2, 3, 4]), 'banana e maribanana gostam de bbananana', "Verifica se funciona quando o substituído é parte do substituto");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.17.1.js"></script>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

A função `replaceString` recebe quatro parâmetros. O primeiro é a string que você quer substituir. O segundo é a string substituta. O terceiro é a string completa na qual haverá as substituições. O quarto é um array contendo os índices em que ocorrerão a substituição, aonde 1 é o primeiro, 2 o segundo, 3 o terceiro, etc. Índices inválidos neste array (0, negativos, ou grandes demais) são ignorados/perdoados. Índices repetidos são ignorados/perdoados. Os índices não precisam estar na ordem.

Você pode verificar nos testes do *snippet* acima, que várias situações são testadas, e em todas elas, o código funciona como o esperado.

Comment: Gostei muito da sua solução! Uma última coisa que gostaria é que caso o último (quarto) parâmetro não seja fornecido, ocorra uma substituição normal, visto que já estarei sabendo de antemão se a palavra-alvo é ou não repetida dentro da sentença. Poderia adicionar mais essa funcionalidade, por favor?

Comment: @eden Feito! :)