# O que é e para que serve TDD?

Tags: terminologia, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Estava dando uma olhada no `PHPUnit` - que é um framework de testes unitários .

Dando uma olhada em alguns tutoriais, me deparei com um termo chamado `TDD`.

O que vem a ser `TDD`? E qual é a utilidade dele no dia-a-dia da programação?

Comment: Não a mesma pergunta dessa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53678/para-que-servem-testes-unit%C3%A1rios-e-quais-as-vantagens?rq=1

Comment: @DiegoF acredito que não. TDD e unit tests costumam andar juntos, contudo você pode fazer TDD com outros tipos de testes, aceptance tests por exemplo. Também nada te impede de usar testes unitários sem usar a metodologia TDD, eu poderia por exemplo fazer os testes unitários após ter implementado minha funcionalidade.

Comment: Primeira vez que peço pra fechar alguma pergunta sua, leva a mal não... Não seria o mesmo que [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19177/testes-tdd-unit-test-qa-e-assemelhados-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dos-conceitos-sobre) ???

Comment: Agora fiquei na duvida, aqui parece um pouco mais especifico, mas a utilidade me parece algo amplo e que talvez isto que o @utluiz 
disse *"A ideia principal é inverter a sequência "tradicional" de desenvolvimento colocando o teste em primeiro lugar, antes da implementação."* responderia, mas estou em duvida agora :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa questão de duplicado é que me confundi: A pergunta deve ser igual para ser marcada, ou a resposta responder a pergunta (que não é duplicada, mas levaria a uma resposta duplicada)?

Comment: Ambos os casos valem como duplicata Wallace, mas só não sei se na outra resposta explica a utilidade da maneira que você necessita entender. De qualquer maneira as vantagens sempre me parecem da necessidade ou de como uma equipe trabalha, então acho que a necessidade é caso a caso, não tenho certeza se a resposta lá responde isto e se eu estou certo :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que deu pra entender sim. Eu só estou  na dúvida se marco ou não ;)

Comment: Como só eu votei deixa ela por enquanto aberta. Talvez precisemos mesmo de uma resposta mais especifica, se for possível responder por causa daquela questão de "caso a caso" de uso.

Comment: Hoje olhei melhor, a resposta do utluiz está ótima e explica bem a relação TDD e testes unitários, mas realmente não parece explicar a "utilidade" no dia a dia e acho que essa é a sua dúvida específica. Vou retirar o voto de fechamento :) boa sorte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDD significa Test Driven Development, é uma metodologia na qual os códigos de testes são escritos primeiro antes mesmo de existir qualquer 'código de produção' isso inclui a definição de uma classe ou método.

Ao longo dos anos percebeu-se que os testes eram negligenciados eram deixados apenas no final do ciclo de desenvolvimento o que gerava prejuizo e muito retrabalho, a ideia do TDD é que seu código falhe o mais rápido possível porque isso é mais fácil de corrigir e seu custo é baixo.

Comment: Achei interessante *a ideia do TDD é que seu código falhe o mais rápido possível porque isso é mais fácil de corrigir*, você explicou de maneira que qualquer um pode entender e com poucas palavras +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado, ainda quero editar to meio sem tempo =\, haha faltou deixar claro que os testes são automaziados, que servem como documentação em alguma situações, o ciclo do TDD, baby stapes etc

Comment: nossa parece ser mais amplo que pensei, mas me parece que respondeu bem o que o AP precisava saber, a vantagem do Dia a dia ... me deu uma ideia pra uma pergunta hehe, estou no celular, depois eu posto :)

Answer (score 2):

TDD vem de "Test Driven Development" que em Português significa "Desenvolvimento Guiado por Testes".

Exige a criação de um teste automático, antes de fazer o código, para quando este estiver pronto, você ter certeza que funciona.

Alguns benefícios de desenvolver com a metodologia:

- Os desenvolvedores se forçam a entender a necessidade antes de começar a programar.
- Um grande número de testes ajuda a garantir que todo o código funciona bem no final.

O argumento contrário é o tempo de desenvolvimento e o custo, já que teria que fazer os testes. De qualquer forma esta parte é controversa porque não é tão fácil de provar tanto um lado quanto de outro e quem defende TDD diz que o tempo total de desenvolvimento acaba sendo menor.