# Como funciona um teste de caixa preta?

Tags: terminologia, testes

Na minha aula de teste de software o professor falou a respeito desse tipo de teste bem superficialmente e acabei não conseguindo perguntar para ele mais detalhes em relação ao teste.

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber como funciona o teste de caixa preta, quais componentes estão envolvidos nele e como ele é executado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O teste de caixa preta é o mais fácil que existe porque ele não depende de detalhes de implementação de como o que está sendo testado trabalha. Para aplicar o teste de caixa preta basta saber interagir com a API pública daquilo, então se for um método basta saber que argumentos passar para ele e que resultado ele te dará. Se for uma classe, poderá fazer o teste apenas entendendo o funcionamento geral dela, como constrói e manipula seu comportamento e estado.

Ele se chama de caixa preta porque você não vê o que tem dentro da caixa.

[image: Entrada -> caixa preta -> saída]

*Black box testing* é apenas uma técnica que pode ser aplicada para [qualquer tipo de teste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101) que esteja fazendo, seja um [teste de unidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53678/101), de integração ou outros.

O teste de caixa preta testa apenas se certos conjuntos produzem o resultado esperado. Ele pega a especificação obtida do problema e aplica seus conceitos para ver se acontece o que se esperava, não importa como ele faz internamente.

Este teste pode ser aplicado por alguém muito ligado em desenvolvimento de software mas que não programa correntemente já que ele não exige conhecimentos específicos avançados de programação, ele não cuida do código.

Ele é fácil de ser aplicado mas difícil de ser feito corretamente pelo mesmo motivo da dificuldade de desenvolver software, ter os requisitos certos e modelar algo que atenda esses requisitos sempre é mais difícil que escrever código que qualquer pode aprender em dias, modelar depende de muita experiência e raciocínio amplo.

Uma das críticas que faço aos testes é que se pode falhar tanto na modelagem, provavelmente você falhará nos testes. Isto não é motivo para não testar, mas é motivo para não dar crédito tão grande aos testes como bala de prata para se obter qualidade em software.

No mundo ideal haveria uma pessoa especificando, outra escreve os códigos e uma terceira criando os testes que garantem que tudo está correto, mas se essa terceira fizer burocraticamente partindo do trabalho da primeira, pouca vantagem tem. E seria bom ter uma que questiona o trabalho de todos, assim é mais fácil achar erros, mas sai caro. Na prática isto raramente acontece e diminui seu valor.

A parte ruim dele é que não garante que tudo o que pode ser executado será. Não se sabe o que pode dar errado por razões variadas. E teste bom é o que testa o que pode dar errado e não testar se dá certo o que se espera. Com o teste de caixa preta você pode tentar valores ruins, mas não pode forçar certas partes executarem de determinada forma porque não sabe o que está lá.

## Caixa Branca

Ele se opõe ao teste de caixa branca que procura avaliar cada detalhe do código. Bem grosso modo (isto está tecnicamente errado, só para fazer uma analogia) podemos dizer que o teste de caixa preta é como programar orientado a objeto e o teste de caixa branca é como programa imperativo. O primeiro cuida da estrutura geral o segundo cuida do detalhe de implementação. O teste de caixa branca cuida do controle de fluxo e as decisões específicas tomadas, mudança de estado interno dos objetos e dos dados locais dos métodos. Ou seja, é o oposto do que a outra resposta cita como exemplo. O exemplo correto ali seria testar cada fio, cada engrenagem no motor, se cada mínimo elemento está se comportando como deveria.

Claro, tem uma infinidade de coisas pra falar sobre isto, mas a seria uma resposta muito ampla.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Tem 3 tipo de testes:

- Caixa preta
- Caixa branca
- Caixa cinza

#### Testar em *caixa preta*

Significa testar apenas as funcionalidades do aplicativo, ou seja, ver se ele faz o que deve fazer, sem ver o código. Tem *input*, tem *output* e conforme no *input* você deve ter o *output* esperado.

Neste caso, quem faz o teste tem o perfil do usuário.

Para isso, ele deve preparar planos de testes a fim de "simular" o que um usuário vai fazer: coisas certas e também coisas erradas, por exemplo: colocar um *CPF* no campo data de nascimento.

#### Testar em caixa branca

Significa testar visualizando o código. Precisa de uma pessoa que sabe ler o código e precisa também de ferramentas para analisar o código.

#### Testar em caixa cinza

Mistura o teste em caixa preta com o teste em caixa branca.

#### Exemplos

Exemplo básico para entender melhor, com o teste de um veiculo:

- **Caixa preta:**

  - Ligar o motor
  - Ligar as luzes
  - Buzinar.
  - Dá certo? O carro esta OK.

- **Caixa branca:**

  - Levamos o carro na oficina onde o mecânico vai olhar o
    motor
  - O mecânico verificará se a bateria esta OK.
  - Dá certo? O carro esta OK.
- **Caixa cinza:**

  - Levamos o carro na oficina e quando o mecânico esta
    olhando o motor, nos ligamos.