# Aplicação só funciona no meu pc

Tags: python, nginx, docker

Gostaria que fosse uma das clássicas piadas de "só roda na minha máquina", mas já estou perdendo a cabeça!

Então tenho uma aplicação de processamento de linguagem natural (NLP) que estou usando docker a estrutura é bem simples tenho um container com o backend em python onde a frase é processada e a comunicação é pelo framework fastapi,

O frontend é usando node/typescript/react quando um usuário escreve uma frase qualquer no form ele faz um POST usando o Axios no endpoint do backend (localhost:8000/process) até aí tá tudo perfeito! Tudo funciona isolado e em conjunto, só que em conjunto só funciona no meu pc! Dentre as soluções já configurei o CORS no fastapi e se eu faço o mesmo procedimento por outro computador só que invés de ir pelo front fazer um POST pelo insomina/postman enfim eles funcionam perfeitamente o backend devolve a resposta direitinho, mas pelo front só vai pelo meu pc! Hoje pela manhã decidi tentar um reverse-proxy usando nginx, porém como não tenho experiência com nginx não sei se está bem configurado, porém, também não funcionou, quando em outro pc eu acesso o frontend e digito a frase a ser processada não há comunicação inclusive uma das funcionalidades é reportar se a frase foi "mal processada" então se o usuário clica em um botão para "reportar" a frase ele é redirecionado pra um endpoint "/frase-reportada" no meu pc vai direitinho, já em outro pc invés de aparecer a frase no endpoint aparece undefined.

Esse é o docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 

rev-proxy-server:
    image: nginx:1.17.10
    container_name: rev_proxy
    depends_on:
        - api
        - client
    volumes:
        - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/ngnix/nginx.conf
    ports:
        - 80:80

api:
    build: ./backend
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker & gunicorn --limit-request-line 0
    volumes: 
        - .:/code
    working_dir:
        /code/backend
    ports: 
        - "8000:8000"

client:
    image: node:12
    ports: 
        - '3000:3000'
    build: ./frontend
    volumes: 
        - .:/front
    working_dir: /front/frontend
    command:  'yarn start'
    
    depends_on: 
        - api
```

e esse é o nginx.conf, caso o error seja mal configuração do reverse-proxy

```
user www-data;
worker_process auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

Imagino que o problema não está nos outros arquivos, pois, isolados funcionam e em conjunto também, só que em conjunto só no meu pc

Enfim realmente não tenho mais ideia do que poderia ser, e ficarei muito grato em receber qualquer direcionamento!

Comment: Respondo sem olhar para os arquivos de configuração que você mostrou: acho bastante improvável que alguém consiga depurar sua aplicação (isto é, encontrar exatamente **onde** está o erro, bem como **como** e **sob quais condições** ele acontece) sem ter acesso a ela. Idealmente você escreveu [testes unitários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53678/para-que-servem-testes-unit%c3%a1rios-e-quais-as-vantagens) para cada aspecto da aplicação, de forma que seja fácil rodar os testes na segunda máquina e descobrir exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo! Consegui resolver, basicamente o axios tava fazendo o post no localhost, por isso só funcionava na minha máquina, daí mudei pra o ip do meu pc e rodou tranquilo sem precisar nem de reverse-proxy! Mas obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como havia dito o frontend fazia um POST no endpoint do backend, na configuração do Axios estava para localhost:8000/process daí obviamente só funcionaria no meu pc, qualquer outro dispositivo tentaria acessar o próprio localhost e falharia, só mudei de

```
const api = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://localhost:8000"
})
```

Para:

```
const api = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://192.168.0.108:8000" //meu IP local e a porta do serviço
})
```